# Como ler um planilha com data e hora no Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Como faço para importar os dados de uma planilha do excel que contém data e hora (ex.: 22/10/14 22:45:10) no Matlab?

Comment: Ola! bem vinda ao SOpt. Para importar um ficheiro excel pode usar a função [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html).

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo:

1. usar o comando xlsread,
2. ou converter o arquivo para o formato csv e então usar o comando csvread,
3. ou se nenhuma dessas soluções lhe satisfizer você pode usar o readtable.

Para o último, vou mostrar como importar um arquivo excel contendo datas para uma tabela no Matlab. Seja o arquivo hipotético peso.xls com os seguintes dados.

```
   Data        Peso
___________    ______

31-Oct-1996    174.8 
29-Nov-1996    179.3 
30-Dec-1996    190.4 
31-Jan-1997    185.7
```

Agora faça o seguinte.

T = readtable('peso.xls')

T =

```
    Data        Peso
____________    ______

'10/31/1996'    174.8 
'11/29/1996'    179.3 
'12/30/1996'    190.4 
'1/31/1997'     185.7
```

No windows, com Excel, a variável Data é um campo string do cell array. Para converte-lo basta fazer:

T.Data = datetime(T.Data,'InputFormat','MM/dd/yyyy')

T =

```
   Data        Peso
___________    ______

31-Oct-1996    174.8 
29-Nov-1996    179.3 
30-Dec-1996    190.4 
31-Jan-1997    185.7
```

Este exemplo foi originalmente posto em [when-to-convert-dates-from-excel-files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/when-to-convert-dates-from-excel-files.html)

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta!

Comment: Imagina, não precisa agradecer. Estamos aqui para isto mesmo.